# How can I get a single column in python and sql?

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to make a book selling system and I am trying to take the book's name from input and find the quantity of the book.But system takes the whole row instead of taking a single column.How can I solve this ?

```py
import sqlite3


print("------------------------------------------")
print("Welcome to the bookshop management system.")
print("------------------------------------------")


print("[1] Add Book")
print("[2] Search for a book")
print("[3] Sell a book")
print("[4] Change stocks")


connect=sqlite3.connect("librarydatabase.db")
cursor=connect.cursor()

Inserter="INSERT INTO books VALUES('booknamevalue','writervalue','DateOfReleasevalue','Quantityvalue','Pagevalue')"
operation=input("Please enter an operation:")


if operation=="1":
    bookname=input("Please enter the book's name")
    writername=input("Please enter the writer's name:")
    DateOfReleaseinput=input("Please enter the Date of release:")
    Quantityvalue=input("Please enter the Quantity of the book:")
    Pagevalue=input("Please enter the Page count of the book:")
    Inserter1=Inserter.replace("booknamevalue",bookname)
    Inserter2=Inserter1.replace("writervalue",writername)
    Inserter3=Inserter2.replace("DateOfReleasevalue",DateOfReleaseinput)
    Inserter4=Inserter3.replace("Quantityvalue",Quantityvalue)
    Inserter5=Inserter4.replace("Pagevalue",Pagevalue)
    cursor.execute(Inserter5)
    connect.commit()


Booksellersearcher="SELECT Quantity FROM Books WHERE Bookname='Booknamevalue'"


#Will be made correctly
if operation=="3":
    Bookname2=input("Please enter the name of the book:")
    Booksellersearcher2=Booksellersearcher.replace("Booknamevalue",Bookname2)
    cursor.execute(Booksellersearcher2)
    BookQuantity=cursor.fetchone()
    if BookQuantity==0:
        print("No Stock On this Book")
        operation=input("Please enter an operation:")
    else:
        print("There are"+" "+str(BookQuantity)+"books"+" "+"of"+" "+Bookname2)
        operationinput=input("Do you wanna sell ?(Y/N)")
        if operationinput=="Y":
            SellingQuantityInput=int(input("How many Books do you wanna sell ?"))
            NewQuantity=BookQuantity-SellingQuantityInput
            print(NewQuantity)
        else:
            operation=input("Please enter an operation:")


Booksearcher="SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Bookname='Booknamevalue'"
if operation=="2":
    Booknameinput2=input("Please enter the name of the book:")
    Booksearcher2=Booksearcher.replace("Booknamevalue",Booknameinput2)
    cursor.execute(Booksearcher2)
    Bookvalues=cursor.fetchall()
    print(Bookvalues)


BookQuantitychanger="UPDATE Books SET Quantity='Quantityvalue' WHERE Bookname='Booknamevalue'"
if operation=="4":
    Booknameinput3=input("Please enter the name of the book:")
    BookQuantityinput=int(input("Please enter the quantity of the book:"))
    BookQuantitychanger2=BookQuantitychanger.replace("Quantityvalue",str(BookQuantityinput))
    BookNamereplacer=BookQuantitychanger2.replace("Booknamevalue",Booknameinput3)
    cursor.execute(BookNamereplacer)
    connect.commit()
    print("Book quantity changed successfully!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I will start with your question, `SELECT` on a table will return rows, which are put in tuples, even you select a single columns it returns the rows containing just this column, but those are still rows, and so tuples.

But now **please** read the following.

Using string replace or any other other string templating for any SQL statement is leaving it wide open for SQL injection, what if the user inputs `' ; DROP TABLE books ; --` in the `Booksearcher` statement ?

You end up with

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Bookname='' ; DROP TABLE books ; --'
```

which will destroy you `books` table.

Please go through the [SQLite3 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-tutorial) to see SQL parameterisation.

Comment: There isn't any 'DROP TABLE ' in my code.Where did you see it ?

Comment: No, not in your code, but if the user inputs a `' ; DROP TABLE books ; --` anywhere you prompt for user input, that is a SQL injection and since you're doing straight string.replace(), then you will pass that to the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is `SELECT *` which is why you get all columns.

Change your SQL statement to the one below:

```py
Booksearcher="SELECT Quantity FROM Books WHERE Bookname='Booknamevalue'"
```

But your code is a bit unreadable.

1. You are using a lot of replacements and for each you're using a new variable. Use f-strings instead.
2. Your variable names are capitalized. In python that's used to define classes/objects.
3. Your if statements should be if/elif instead.
4. There is no main loop, so your code only executes once.
5. You have what I would call main menu prints inside your submenus. Instead you should go back to the main menu.
6. [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

I did a quick rewrite of your code because I'm a bit bored. See below

```py
import sqlite3


connect = sqlite3.connect("librarydatabase.db")
cursor = connect.cursor()


while True:
    print("------------------------------------------")
    print("Welcome to the bookshop management system.")
    print("------------------------------------------")
    print("[1] Add Book")
    print("[2] Search for a book")
    print("[3] Sell a book")
    print("[4] Change stocks")
    print("[0] Exit")
    operation = input("Please enter an operation:\n")


    if operation == "1":
        bookname = input("Please enter the book's name:\n")
        writername = input("Please enter the writer's name:\n")
        dateofrelease = input("Please enter the Date of release:\n")
        quantity = input("Please enter the Quantity of the book:\n")
        pagecount = input("Please enter the Page count of the book:\n")
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO books VALUES('{bookname}','{writername}','{dateofrelease}','{quantity}','{pagecount}')")
        connect.commit()

    elif operation == "2":
        bookname = input("Please enter the name of the book:\n")
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT Quantity FROM Books WHERE Bookname='{bookname}'")
        books = cursor.fetchall()
        print(books)

    elif operation == "3":
        bookname = input("Please enter the name of the book:\n")
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT Quantity FROM Books WHERE Bookname='{bookname}'")
        bookquantity = cursor.fetchone()
        if bookquantity == 0:
            print("No Stock On this Book")
            # go to the start of the while loop
            continue
        else:
            print(f"There are {bookquantity} books of {bookname}")
            operationinput = input("Do you wanna sell ?(Y/N):\n")
            if operationinput.upper() == "Y":
                sellingquantity = int(input("How many Books do you wanna sell ?\n"))
                newquantity = bookquantity - sellingquantity
                print(newquantity)
            else:
                continue

    elif operation == "4":
        bookname = input("Please enter the name of the book:\n")
        bookquantity = int(input("Please enter the quantity of the book:\n"))
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE Books SET Quantity='{bookquantity}' WHERE Bookname='{bookname}'")
        connect.commit()
        print("Book quantity changed successfully!")

    elif operation == "0":
        # exit while loop
        break

    else:
        print("Operation not recognized.")
```